# 2D arrays passed through functions in c

Tags: c, function, pointers, multidimensional-array

I'm having a problem with my program. I need my program to read from a text file, the first consists of the dimensions of the 2d array the rest is the contents of the array. I have coded the readWord function which reads from textfiles and it works but when i do anything on the main function with the array it crashes. Please could you help.

```
int main()

{
       int num_it, cols, rows;
       char** myworld;

       num_it = readWorld(myworld,&cols, &rows);

       myworld[1][2]='x';/*it crashes when i make this statement*/

}


int readWorld(char** world, int* width,int* height)
{
  int result=0,i,cols=0,rows=0;
  char buff[25];

   FILE* file = fopen ("world.txt", "r");

   fscanf(file, "%d %d %d\n", width, height, &result);

   /*Dynamic allocation*/
   world = (char**)malloc(*(height)* sizeof(char*));
    for(i=0;i<*height;i++)
    {
        world[i] = (char*)malloc(*width*sizeof(char));
    }

    /*store data in array*/
    while(fgets(buff, sizeof buff, file) != NULL)
    {
       if (strlen(buff) >1){

       for(cols=0; cols<=(strlen(buff)); ++cols)
       {
          world[rows][cols] = buff[cols];
       }      
       ++rows;
    }
}
```

fclose(file);

return result;

}

Comment: `num_it = readWorld(myworld,&cols, &rows);` change `&myworld` and `int readWorld(char** world, int* width,int* height)` change `char***world` and `world = (char**)malloc(*(height)* sizeof(char*));` change `*world` because Can not reflect the change of pointer that is passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `myworld` variable in main is never initialized and points to junk, so when you try to access it bad things happen. Think about why: you are passing a **copy** of the variable to `readWorld`. You correctly allocate memory inside there, and make the **copy** point to it, but the original pointer (in `main`) still points to whatever random location it pointed to before.

If you want the memory for it to be allocated inside the `readWorld` function and made accessible via the `myworld` variable in `main` then you must pass a *pointer* to `myworld` to `readWorld`; in other words, you must pass a *triple* pointer.

Try this:

```
int readWorld(char*** world, int* width,int* height)
{ 
    char **tempworld = malloc(...);

    // do whatever

    *world = tempworld;

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    char **myworld = NULL;

    readWorld(&myworld, ...);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate the memory for myworld in the actual caller!

What's happening here is that you are passing the pointer by value to the function.

The pointer value is changed by the function but that's not going to adjust the one in the caller.

Two options: use a triple indirection (ie pass a pointer to the the pointer) or allocate in the main sub. I prefer the latter, mainly because you can control the memory deallocation in a more symmetrical manner; even if you fixed this problem your code still has the memory leak.

What you're experiencing is undefined behaviour as you are attempting to access memory your program does not own.

Comment: This is `C`, there's no "pass by reference" as in C++.

Comment: Third possibility to to have `readWorld` return the `char **` it allocates and fills (or NULL if there's a problem).

Comment: @NikBougalis: C does have pass-by-reference -- it's just done explicitly by using `&` on the passed variable and making the parameter a pointer, and it existed long before C++ was even thought of.  Just becuase C++ has something completely different called pass-by-reference doesn't change this.

Comment: @ChrisDodd We can argue semantics if you'd like. I don't think my comment is inaccurate or incorrect.